# KML scalability? Use KML to show and filter 1600+ points in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

Will you guys tell me whether or not this solution will work before I spend a lot of time learning/researching KML?  (It looks like I need to learn it at some point, but I have a deadline to meet, first.)

Background - I need to plot 1662 points on a map that fall into 7 categories.  I would like to show all, as well as filter/show only categories that the user chooses.

My first attempt at this used the Google Maps API.  I created GeoPoints, added them to an ItemizedOverlay, and then added the ItemizedOverlay to the map.  That works great for a few points.  100 points only took 3 seconds.  By the time I got up to 400 points, things really started to slow down (like 30 seconds or so).  I loaded all 1662, and it took 15 minutes!

1)  Why does this take so long?  Does the API make a call to Google Maps for each point?

2)  I found KML as a possible alternative.  How well does KML scale?  Will it be able to plot and load 1600+ points?  If not, can you recommend another solution?

3)  How do you recommend I go about filtering my categories?  Currently, I plan on loading each category to a layer.  I found references to hiding/showing layers, so I'm going to try to do that.  Is this a good approach?

4)  How can I add buttons?  Can/should I add them to an overlay?  If not, is it possible to have the map open in a MapView and then control the filter/show with Android Buttons?

I'm sorry if my questions sound basic.  I will continue researching and learning on my own.  However, I want to know whether or not my solution will work at all before I waste another week going down another dead end.

Thanks in advance!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Android, but I am working on a project where I generate KML output from a Java application. I'm not sure what kind of constraints you have when working with Android Java, but if you can you should try the following open source library:

[JAK - Java API for KML](http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home)

It will make the KML creation fairly easy. I can't answer your question about scalability on Android since I have no experience with it.

Comment: I ended up restricting my data points to one state at a time.  However, I'm accepting this answer, because of the useful API.  Thanks.